# ios - how to move to a particular UI viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

in my app i have a tabbar. The `UI tabbar controller` has  five indexes. Each indexes consists of `5 UI view controllers`.

In some conditions if i click a button i want to open a particular view controller placed in the 0th index of the tab bar.

How to open that view controller alone directly, pls help me friends....

Answer (score 0):

You can send the index of the tab you want to select with your push notification (see here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1 for more info)

Answer (score 0):

first add a view as subview to the tabbar and then hide and show the view whereever you needs

```
 UIView *firstview=[[UIView alloc] init];
    [tabbarObject.view addsubview:firstview];

    tabbar object i added to window
    [self.window addsubview:tabbarObject];
```